# Regex Extract Everything until a + sign in Google SQL

Tags: sql, regex

I have a string that looks like this:

```
  DS Name: Moody: MOODY_TYPE_PRIO_XPER_CH+889 -
```

I want to regex extract everything until the + sign.

Here is the query that I have so far which extracts everything:

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(col_name, r'(\DS Name:.+ - *\b)'
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
DS Name: Moody: MOODY_TYPE_PRIO_XPER_CH
```

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep it simple and just use the pattern `^[^+]+`:

```sql
SELECT REGEX_EXTRACT(col_name, r'^[^+]+') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```